# How to compare instances of protocols and instances of classes

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a protocol:

```
protocol MasterGame {}
```

and a class that produces a singleton

```
class MasterGameImp : MasterGame {
    static let sharedInstance = MasterGameImp()
}
```

Now I have another object that has a dependency on the protocol and has the property injected by it's instantiator.

```
class MyGameObject {
    var masterGame: MasterGame?
}
```

I want to write a unit test to test that the singleton is injected properly into an instance of MyGameObject. What is the right way to do this? `===` does not accept arguments of type MasterGame and MasterGameImp. So apparently you can't check sameness that way between a protocol and a class. So I need another way to check sameness between the singleton and the stored property. Thanks!

Comment: `==`??? Honestly I do not really understand what you are asking? How to compare to objects!?

Comment: `==` is the check for equality. `===` is the check for sameness, (i.e. are the objects the exact same instantiation). So what I am trying to write a test for is that the stored property and the singleton are the exact same object.

Comment: Yes!? So what, where is the problem? If === returns yields false you apparently found a bug using your unit test or the test is wrong. I don't know how we can help you!

Comment: You cannot compare an instance of a protocol and an instance of a class with the `===` operator in swift. It won't compile. I'm trying to find an alternative.

Comment: Simplified a lot: http://pastebin.com/iDep2f1y is that your issue?

Comment: Yes, exactly, and as a unit test that works perfectly for me right now. If you can post that as an answer, I'd like to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue very much simplified is the following:

```
protocol P {
}

class X : P {
}

let x = X()
let p : P = x

print(x === p)
```

> Binary operator `===` cannot be applied to operands of type 'X' and 'P'

```
print((x as P) === p)
```

> Binary operator `===` cannot be applied to two 'P' operands

```
print(x === (p as! X))
```

> **true** -> Working

What you have to do is upcast the protocol to its implementation, which es really not pretty at all :/

I did not find a better solution, it has something to do how swift handles protocols different than regular class inheritance. Changing to `class P` will result in all three above statements to succeed.

As @matt noted the code will of course crash if you incorrectly provide a wrong p which is not really a `X`. To solve that issue you should wrap the check into a if-condition:

```
if let xp = p as? X {
    print(x === xp)
} else {
    print("p is not of type X")
}
```

Comment: You don't want to say `as!` because that will crash if the cast fails.

Comment: @matt Xcode tells me that I **have** to use `as!`. But you are of course correct in that if you provide a p which is not really a X the code will crash.

Comment: @matt is the added if-wrap the better way!?

Comment: For the purposes of my question, the `as!` works because it's for a unit test, but I agree that it wouldn't be a good choice for live code.

Comment: Absolutely and _especially_ for unit test you should go all the way use the more verbose `as?` test. This allows the test to fail in good order. Failure is much better than crashing. :)

Comment: It's a personal opinion. In my case, for writing a unit test for a singleton sameness, I would actually prefer that there be a fatal error. Given the catastrophic consequences for this not being correct in usage, I like the catastrophic consequences in the tests. I think it stresses the issue more than seeing 99/100 tests passed in my CI environment.

Comment: There is no reason to crash a test, the test should go on.